# ¿Cómo hago para guardar correctamente la matriz?

Tags: java, android, json, array

Buenas, estoy tratando de meter una playlist de canciones (discos y canciones) que obtengo desde un JSON en un array bidimensional o matriz

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray discos = jsonObj.getJSONArray("discos");

discosNuevos = new MusicaObj[discos.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < discos.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = discos.getJSONObject(i);

    String nombre = c.getString("nombre");
    String logo = c.getString("portada");
    String artista = c.getString("artista");
    int nCanciones = c.getInt("total");

    JSONArray canciones = c.getJSONArray("canciones");

    cancionesDisco = new Canciones[discos.length()][canciones.length()];
    for(int j = 0; j < canciones.length();j++) {
        JSONObject s = canciones.getJSONObject(j);
        String urlCanciones = s.getString("url");
        String nombreCanciones = s.getString("nombre");
        int ordenCancion = s.getInt("orden");
        cancionesDisco[i][j] = new Canciones(urlCanciones, nombreCanciones, ordenCancion);

    }
    discosNuevos[i] = new MusicaObj(logo, nombre, artista, nCanciones);
```

Se entiende que i es el índice del disco. El caso es que a la hora de ver el contenido de esta matriz, solo puedo ver las canciones del último disco

edit: La previsualización del listado de canciones es a traves de este for, una vez se pulse sobre el disco selecccionado:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fin; i++) {


     String texto = cancionesDisco[discoActual][i].getNombreCancion();
     btnCanciones[i] =  new Button(getApplicationContext());

        txtID = "tbrs"+compruebaRow;
        resoID = getResources().getIdentifier(txtID, "id", getPackageName());
      TableRow txtR = (TableRow) findViewById(resoID);


    txtR .addView(btnCanciones[i]);
    btnCanciones[i].setText(texto);
    Resources r = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    int wpx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            400,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
    int hpx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            60,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
    btnCanciones[i].getLayoutParams().width=wpx;
    btnCanciones[i].getLayoutParams().height=hpx;
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) btnCanciones[i].getLayoutParams();
    params.leftMargin = 2; params.topMargin = 2; params.rightMargin = 2; params.bottomMargin = 2;
    btnCanciones[i].setLayoutParams(params);
    btnCanciones[i].setId(i);
    final int x = i;
    btnCanciones[i].setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {



                if(checkRadio) {
                    playerExo.stop();
                    playerExo.release();
                    playerExo = null;

                }
               cancionesDisco[discoActual][x].getUrlCancion());
                setUpVideoView(cancionesDisco[discoActual][x].getUrlCancion(), cancionesDisco[discoActual][x].getOrdenCancion(), CanalesNuevos[discoActual].getnCanciones());

            }
            return false;
        }


    });



}
```

Comment: La estructura de datos es "curiosa"... ¿todos los discos tienen el mismo número de canciones?

Comment: Si no iteras sobre i te va a sobreescribir en cada pasada de j.

Comment: @SJuan76 No, cada disco tiene un número de canciones diferente

Comment: @Lithorell Un for anidado se encarga de incrementar el valor de i.

Comment: Pon el codigo entero para que lo podamos ver desde la perspectiva completa.

Comment: @Lithorell hecho

Comment: Pon tambien como ves el contenido del array.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de la estructura de tu .json por favor.

Comment: @Lithorell editado

Comment: @Jorgesys {"discos":
[{"ID":"1","portada":"portada",
"nombre":"nombre",
"artista":"artsta",
"canciones":
[{"ID":"135","ID_DISCO":"1","url":"url","orden":"0","nombre":"nombre"},
{"ID":"136","ID_DISCO":"1","url":"url","orden":"1","nombre":"nombre"}],
"total":2}

Comment: ¿Porque no te generas un objeto disco con id(int), portada(String), nombre(String), artista(String), canciones(List o ArrayList), total(int) ? Por supuesto canciones es un List o ArrayList de objetos Cancion que tendrá las propiedades Id(int), Id_disco(int), url(String), orden(String) y nombre(String). Con esto puedes deserializa el json y ya tendrás los discos con sus propiedades y será mucho más rápido y cómodo recorrerlos. Si modelas bien el objeto, te rellenará todos sus parámetros y no te dará problemas de que no te pilla todas las canciones

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Conseguido. Muchísimas grácias

Comment: Me alegro, yo siempre que trabajo con json intento deserializarlo en objetos ya que luego a la hora de recorrerlos u obtener información es mucho más cómodo y más eficiente, además te evitarás errores al no tratar cadenas de esa manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguido a través de un arraylist

```
sonsArrList = new ArrayList[discos.length()];


                for (int i = 0; i < discos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = discos.getJSONObject(i);

                    String nombre = c.getString("nombre");
                    String logo = c.getString("portada");
                    String artista = c.getString("artista");
                    int nCanciones = c.getInt("total");

                    JSONArray canciones = c.getJSONArray("canciones");

                    sonsArrList[i] = new ArrayList<>();
                    cancionesDisco = new Canciones[discos.length()][canciones.length()];

                    for(int j = 0; j < canciones.length();j++) {

                        JSONObject s = canciones.getJSONObject(j);
                        String urlCanciones = s.getString("url");
                        String nombreCanciones = s.getString("nombre");
                        int ordenCancion = s.getInt("orden");
                        cancionesDisco[i][j] = new Canciones(urlCanciones, nombreCanciones, ordenCancion);
                        sonsArrList[i].add(j, cancionesDisco[i][j]);

                    }
                    CanalesNuevos[i] = new MusicaObj(logo, nombre, artista, sonsArrList[i], nCanciones);
```

Muchas gracias de nuevo a @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: veo que lo haces recorriendo el json, prueba a deserializarlo "a saco" con la librería de Gson, sólo tendrías que hacer: Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();
List<YourClass> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType); con estas 2 líneas ya tendrías tu listado de discos completado